# how to reset the initial value to the first value after each condition executed in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, testing, automated-tests

How to reset the loop to the first value.
here when i am executing it is working bothe loops onwin,onloss and goal loop.
but i need to reset the loop to the first row(engine.Number(roundBit(currentNumber), currentrow);) as fresh after executing the goal loop.
but its not working i think i forgot some loops here.
first execution onwin conditions
second execution onloss conditions
untill reach the goal.
after reaching the goal it should be reset to the starting number

pls help me on this.....
thanks

```js
engine.Number(roundBit(currentNumber), currentrow);
// engine.Number(currentNumber, config.baserow.value);

engine.on('GAME_STARTING', onGameStarted);
engine.on('GAME_ENDED', onGameEnded);

function onGameStarted() {
    engine.Number(roundBit(currentNumber), currentrow);
    // engine.Number(currentNumber, config.baserow.value);
}

function onGameEnded() {
    var lastGame = engine.history.first();

    // If we wagered, it means we played
    if (!lastGame.wager) {
        return;
    }

    // we won..
    if (lastGame.cashedAt) {
        if (config.win.value === 'baseBit') {
            currentNumber = config.baseNumber.value;

        } else if (config.win.value === 'increaseBit') {
            console.assert(config.win.value === 'increaseBit');
            currentNumber *= config.win.options.increaseBit.value;
        }

        if (config.win1.value === 'baserow') {
            currentrow = config.baserow.value;
            // log('won, so resetting row to', currentrow)
        } else if (config.win1.value === 'increaserow') {
            console.assert(config.win1.value === 'increaserow');
            currentrow += config.win1.options.increaserow.value;
        }

        log('We won, so next Number will be', currentNumber / 100, 'bits', ' and, next row well be', currentrow)

    } else {
        // damn, looks like we lost :(
        if (config.loss.value === 'baseBit') {
            currentNumber = config.baseNumber.value;
        } else if (config.loss.value === 'increaseBit') {
            console.assert(config.loss.value === 'increaseBit');
            currentNumber*= config.loss.options.increaseBit.value;
        }

        if (config.loss1.value === 'baserow') {
            currentrow = config.baserow.value;
            // log('lost, so resetting row to', currentrow)
        } else if (config.loss1.value === 'increaserow') {
            console.assert(config.loss1.value === 'increaserow');
            currentrow += config.loss1.options.increaserow.value;
        }

        log('We lost, so next Number will be', currentNumber / 100, 'bits', ' and, next row will be', currentrow)
    }
  // handling handle profit
  if (goal <= userInfo.balance/100){
  log('arned', prft, 'bits from', startingBalance);
  }

    // handling handle minimum Number
    if (currentNumber <= config.stop.value) {
        currentrow = config.baserow.value;
        currentNumber = config.baseNumber.value;
    }

  //

    if (currentNumber < config.stop.value) {
        log('Was about to Number', currentNumber, 'which triggers the stop');
        engine.removeListener('GAME_STARTING', onGameStarted);
        engine.removeListener('GAME_ENDED', onGameEnded);
    }
   
  // handling handle maximum Number
    if (currentNumber >= config.stop1.value) {
        currentrow = config.baserow.value;
        currentNumber = config.baseNumber.value;
    }

    //

    if (currentNumber > config.stop1.value) {
        log('Was about to Number', currentNumber, 'which triggers the stop');
        engine.removeListener('GAME_STARTING', onGameStarted);
        engine.removeListener('GAME_ENDED', onGameEnded);
    }

}

function roundBit(Number) {
    return Math.round(Number / 100) * 100;
}
```

Comment: What is behind the variable `engine` ?

Comment: it is not variable. it is system...